# Location Client request location updates with parcelable extras in PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-location

I am using LocationClient with PendingIntent to get location updates.

```
PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, OnLocationAvail.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

The Above code works fine I get the location from the key LocationClient.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED

But when I have an extras of parcelable data as described below, the service gets called with the parcelable data but the key LocationClient.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED in the intent extras is always null.

```
Intent callbackIntent = new Intent(context, OnLocationAvail.class);
callbackIntent.putExtra(SOME_KEY, PARCELABLE_DATA);
PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, callbackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Where you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was when the LocationClient pushes an update via the callback PendingIntent, the process doesn't has any information of the ClassLoader since it is happening outside the application context and in a different process.

The following link helped me to narrow down the issue.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6822

Solution:

Use a hack bundle when requesting for an location update.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("com.foo.parcel", some_parcel);
callbackPendingIntent.putExtra("com.foo.bundle",bundle);
```

When receiving the location update.

```
Bundle oldBundle = intent.getBundleExtra("com.foo.bundle");      
some_parcel = oldBundle.getParcelable("com.foo.parcel");
```