# Including data in location request pendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am requesting a series of location updates with a `PendingIntent`, with a `BroadcastReceiver` set up to handle the location updates. Here is a sample `PendingIntent`:

```
    Intent locationIntent = new Intent(context, LocationReceiver.class);
    locationIntent.putExtra("foo", "bar");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, locationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Here is the code requesting the location updates:

```
    final LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
    request.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    request.setExpirationDuration(WAKEUP_DELTA * 2);
    request.setNumUpdates(NUM_UPDATES);
    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    request.setLocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(locationClient, request, pendingIntent);
```

The problem is this: it seems that if I include any extras at all in the intent, the Location does not get included. That is, when I call `intent.getExtras().get(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);` the result is null. If I do not add extras to my `Intent`, the `Location` is present in the extras!

I tried various workarounds, including various iterations of [Location Client request location updates with parcelable extras in PendingIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303057/location-client-request-location-updates-with-parcelable-extras-in-pendingintent) but that does not seem to work for me. Is there any way to work around this short of coming up with some method to store the extras elsewhere and retrieve them when the location receiver is executed? Or am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/issues/32

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this @Catherine ?

Answer (score -1):

Apologies for answering so late. But for anyone who might still be looking here is the answer i found:-
Both LocationResult and LocationAvailability are sent to the given PendingIntent. You can extract data from an Intent using hasResult(Intent), extractResult(Intent), hasLocationAvailability(Intent), and extractLocationAvailability(Intent).
After that just use the code that you use inside LocationCallbacks.
[FusedLocationProviderClient RequestLocationUpdate](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent))